# Specific command sequence with sudo and file permissions

Tags: permissions, sudo

I need to allow a certain user access to these commands:

```
sudo sync
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

(This particular developer is doing some DB performance testing and flushing the fs cache gives them cleaner numbers, so please refrain from comments on why we're using this command.)

Can I restrict the user to a very specific command with sudo, e.g. `tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`?

From what I understand, I can only restrict them to the command `tee` itself.  I don't want to allow the user to be able to use `tee` as root on anything they want, however.

I guess the other option is to give them write access to that particular file, but is that crazy talk, i.e. giving some non-admin write access to a file in `/proc`?

Any pointers or ideas on the best way to restrict this are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sudo accepts command line arguments. So, you can very well go ahead and make changes to sudoers file such that tee is allowed when the argument is /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches for everything else, sudo will deny execution. If you want a tighter execution, drop in a neat and tidy shell script replacement under somewhere in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin with tighter permissions and then in sudoers configuration, allow users to execute the script as root on that particular host.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear.  Every example I've come across only shows one specific command without arguments.  Do you have an example of the syntax for the sudoers file?

Comment: I would be inclined to better go for a shell script, even if it could be only minimal lines. This way, you will be for sure aware that you have restricted users to only one shell script to run as root on a particular host and shell script does not do anything apart from just clearing the cache under sudo environment, no argument parsing no muckup with external resources.

Comment: though man sudoers is sufficient; an online read may give you a quick start http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch09_:_Linux_Users_and_Sudo

Comment: If you are going for putting tee into sudoers file directly, then use the fullpath of the tee command.

Comment: I put the commands into a shell script and dropped that into /usr/bin with appropriate permissions, then restricted the user to only /usr/bin/thescript.  Thanks for the help.